# How to quickly sum a range of indexes in multiple arrays in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, sum, equation

Im trying to reconstruct a HDR image using an equation where i have to sum across j values (0-15) in both the numerator and the denominator for each i value. Is there a faster way to do this? Using perhaps np.sum?

g is an 1D array thats 255 long that remaps all pixel values.

lEks is log exposure times for the 15 images

Z is an array with size [95488, 15], first dimension is pixel index and second is image number

```
def genHDR(Z,g,lEks):

    Zi, Zj = Z.shape        #[95488, 15]
    HDRimage= np.zeros(Zi)

    for i in range(Zi):
        numerator   = 0
        denominator = 0

        for j in range(Zj):
            numerator   +=(Z[i,j])*(g[Z[i,j]] - lEks[j])
            denominator +=(Z[i,j])

        HDRimage[i] = numerator/denominator
    return HDRimage
```

Comment: what are the variables `g` and `lEks`?

Comment: g is an array 255 long that remaps the pixel values, lEks is log exposure times for the 15 images

Comment: Numpy is a vectorized library (with most code written in C, so very fast). So you don't use for loops (very slow in Python).  Say you have an array `time=np.arange(0,1,100)` i.e. containing [0,0.01,..,.0.99]. To apply a function to all of the elements you can write `np.sin(2*np.pi*f*time)`   after defining f to some frequency. In your case you can use the numpy function `np.sum()` instead of adding in a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this would be to use np.Array.sum(axis=1). Assuming that the g(Z[i,j]) call is valid. You actually dont even need any loops:

```
import numpy as np

Z = np.random.randint(0,255,(10,15))
g=np.random.randint(0,10,(256))
lEks = np.random.rand((15))

def genHDR(Z,g,lEks):
    numerator = (Z*(g[Z]-lEks.view().reshape((1,)+ lEks.shape))).sum(axis=1)
    denominator = Z.sum(axis=1)
    HDRimage = numerator/denominator
    return HDRimage
```

Comment: Yep. Very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

@Dillman beat me to it. Maybe you can still use the below as to how to construct this. I like to think in steps.

```
import numpy as np

Z=  np.random.randint(low=0,high=256,size=(6,3))   # assume just 3 images with 6 pixels each
print(f' Z= {Z}')

lEks=np.random.rand(3)
print(f'lEks = {lEks}')

g0=np.arange(255)   #some example mapping; here from byte to half byte
g= g0//2        # // integer division


npxl,nimage=np.shape(Z)
print(f'npxl={npxl} nimage={nimage}')

# vectorize just one operation at first, easier to visualize
hdr=np.zeros(npxl)

for i in np.arange(npxl):
    #print(Z[i])
    denom=np.sum(Z[i])
    hdr[i]= np.sum(Z[i] *(g[Z[i]]- lEks))/denom 
    # Z[i] is just a vector of length 3, just like lEks

print(hdr)

# this would do it, but still be slower than necessary, as your remaining loop has many more elements that 
# the one we dealt with


# now vectorize the other coordinate (remove the remaining for-loop)
hdr=np.zeros(npxl)
hdr=  np.sum(Z *(g[Z]- lEks), axis=1)/ np.sum(Z,axis=1)   # which axis to sum over is critical
print(hdr)

#final code

def genHDR(Z, g, lEks):
    npxl,nimage=np.shape(Z)
    hdr=np.zeros(npxl)
    hdr=  np.sum(Z *(g[Z]- lEks), axis=1)/ np.sum(Z,axis=1) 
    return hdr


print(genHDR(Z,g,lEks))
```

output:

```
 Z= [[199 101  67]
 [134  16 137]
 [219   5 135]
 [153  19  17]
 [238  41 120]
 [ 93  50 179]]
lEks = [0.57778608 0.18113957 0.85257974]
npxl=6 nimage=3
[72.94714613 63.50130665 91.04028102 62.58551969 90.46303414 65.97390417]
[72.94714613 63.50130665 91.04028102 62.58551969 90.46303414 65.97390417]
[72.94714613 63.50130665 91.04028102 62.58551969 90.46303414 65.97390417]
```